# How to pass variable to another function flask

Tags: python, variables, flask

Ive made flask function to watermark a pdf file :

```
@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():

pdf_file = request.files['file']
watermark = "watermark.pdf"
merged_file = "merged.pdf"

input_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

watermark_file = open(watermark,'rb')
watermark_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(watermark_file)

pdf_page = input_pdf.getPage(0)

watermark_page = watermark_pdf.getPage(0)

pdf_page.mergePage(watermark_page)

output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

output.addPage(pdf_page)

merged_file = open(merged_file,'wb')
output.write(merged_file)

merged_file.close()
watermark_file.close()
pdf_file.close()

return redirect(url_for("encrypt", file=merged_file))
```

How can i pass the 'merged_file' variable to another function in flask?

I want the watermarked pdf file to enter another function to be encrypt and decrypted. Below are the function:

```
@app.route("/<file>")
def encrypt(file):

key = Fernet.generate_key()

file = open('key.key', 'wb')
file.write(key)
file.close()

file = open('key.key', 'rb')
key = file.read()
file.close()

# with open ('mykey.key', 'wb') as mykey:
#     mykey.write(key)  

# with open('mykey.key', 'rb') as mykey:
#     key = mykey.read()

# print(key)

with open({file}, 'rb') as original_file:
    original = original_file.read()

f = Fernet(key)
encrypted = f.encrypt(original)

with open('test1.pdf', 'wb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted_file.write(encrypted)

f = Fernet(key)

with open('test1.pdf', 'rb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted = encrypted_file.read()

decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)

with open('test2.pdf', 'wb') as decrypted_file:
    decrypted_file.write(decrypted)

return "Success encrypt"
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc\test.py", line 98, in encrypt
    with open({file}, 'rb') as original_file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not set
```

What should i replace at the {file} at line 98? Please help. Thank you

Comment: have you tried to use just `file` without the `{ }`?

Comment: yes ive tried it. output the same error File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc\test.py", line 98, in encrypt
    with open(file, 'rb') as original_file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `file` is a file object you opened in line 6, so I change the variable name,
Try this :

```
@app.route("/<file>")
def encrypt(file):

key = Fernet.generate_key()

file1 = open('key.key', 'wb')
file1.write(key)
file1.close()

file2 = open('key.key', 'rb')
key = file2.read()
file2.close()

# with open ('mykey.key', 'wb') as mykey:
#     mykey.write(key)  

# with open('mykey.key', 'rb') as mykey:
#     key = mykey.read()

# print(key)

with open(str(file), 'rb') as original_file:
    original = original_file.read()

f = Fernet(key)
encrypted = f.encrypt(original)

with open('test1.pdf', 'wb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted_file.write(encrypted)

f = Fernet(key)

with open('test1.pdf', 'rb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted = encrypted_file.read()

decrypted = f.decrypt(encrypted)

with open('test2.pdf', 'wb') as decrypted_file:
    decrypted_file.write(decrypted)

return "Success encrypt"
```

Comment: After I run the code, I got the following error: 
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc\test.py", line 98, in encrypt
    with open(file, 'rb') as original_file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.BufferedWriter name='merged.pdf'>"

Comment: I am not sure, but  try `str(file)` instead of `file`, hope it will works

Comment: I still get the same error: File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc\test.py", line 98, in encrypt with open(file, 'rb') as original_file: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.BufferedWriter name='merged.pdf'>" It stated that I need to do something to 'merged.pdf'

Comment: have you tried to write `'merged.pdf'` instead of `file`, to test if the problem is with the paramter, try also  `{{file}}`, I am sorry I am trying to help even if I didn't understand well the problem, hope will someone will answer you as soon as possible

Comment: thank you so much. from function upload_file(), i changed 'file="merged.pdf"' it worked :)